# C++Builder get strings from TStringList?

Tags: c++builder

I can find samples using Delphi but not C++Builder for getting strings from the `TStringList` but doesn't seem to work the same for C++Builder.

```
TStringList *psl=new TStringList;
psl->Add(_D("String1"));
psl->Add(_D("String2"));

for (UINT i=0;i<psl->Count;i++) {
  String s=psl[i]; // this won't compile!!
  String sv=psl->Values[i]; // blank string
}
```

What am I missing?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the inherited [`TStrings::Strings[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Strings) property, eg:

```cpp
String s = psl->Strings[i];
```

Delphi has a concept of a *default* property in classes, but only for [array-style properties](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Array_Properties):

> The definition of an array property can be followed by the `default` directive, in which case the array property becomes the default property of the class. For example:
>
> ```
>  type
>     TStringArray = class
>      public
>         property Strings[Index: Integer]: string ...; default;
>            ...
>      end;
> ```
>
> If a class has a `default` property, you can access that property with the abbreviation `object[index]`, which is equivalent to `object.property[index]`. For example, given the declaration above, `StringArray.Strings[7]` can be abbreviated to `StringArray[7]`. A class can have only one default property with a given signature (array parameter list), but it is possible to overload the default property. Changing or hiding the default property in descendent classes may lead to unexpected behavior, since the compiler always binds to properties statically.

The `Strings[]` property is the `default` property for the `TStrings` class, which `TStringList` derives from:

```pascal
property Strings[Index: Integer]: string read Get write Put; default;
                                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

This is why `psl.Strings[i]` can be simplified to `psl[i]` in Pascal, but not in C++.

However, in C++, there is an [`operator[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.operator_H5BH5D) defined on the `TStrings` class, which acts as a proxy for the `Strings[]` property.  You can use that operator instead, you would just need to deference your `TStringList*` pointer to reach that operator, eg:

```cpp
String s = (*psl)[i];
// equivalent to:
// String s = psl->operator[](i);
```

Answer (score 1):

For C++Builder use:

`psl->Strings[i]`